# How to achieve multiple event fires & events memory (features of events & promises combined)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, promise

## My requirements

Because of the asynchronous architecture of my applications I am looking for an 'event' system which has the following two two properties:

1. The events should be able to fire multiple times (possible with events, but not with promises)
2. When I start listening for an event that has already been fired, I want the listener to fire once immediately (as with promises)

The reason for 1. is that there are a lot of events (e.g. the updating of certain data) that I want to be able to fire multiple times. But I would like to combine this with 2. so that if an event has already fired upon adding the listener, this listener gets called immediately. This is because I'm not always sure (and I don't want to be sure) which piece of code gets run first.

## My 'solution'

I have thought up the following solution. I'm using this in an AngularJS application therefore the AngularJS context, but the question is applicable for Javascript in general. Note that I simplified the code.

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function(CustomEventEmitter){

    // Broadcast an event. No listener added so nothing happens
    CustomEventEmitter.broadcast('event');

    // Add the event listener. Because the event allready fired, the listener gets called immediatly
    CustomEventEmitter.on('event', function(){
        console.log('Event emitted');
    });

    // Broadcast an other event
    CustomEventEmitter.broadcast('event');

});

app.service('CustomEventEmitter', function(){

    var
        listeners = {},
        memory = [];

    this.broadcast = function(name){

        // The normal broadcasting of the event to the listener
        if(listeners[name]) {
            listeners[name].forEach(function(listener){
                listener();
            });
        }

        // Push the event into the 'memory'
        memory.push(name);
    };

    this.on = function(name, listener){

        // The normal adding of the listener
        if(!listeners[name]) {
            listeners[name] = [];
        }
        listeners[name].push(listener);

        // If an event is already in memory, call the listener
        if(memory.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
            listener();
        }

    };

});
```

## My questions

My questions are these:

1. What is the 'best practice' solution for my requirements?
2. What do you think of my 'solution'?
3. Am I missing something completely obvious?

The reason for the last question is that it seems to me that this is a very common design paradigm but I seem unable to find the best way to solve this in simple and concise way.

## Note

I understand this can be solved with the adding of extra code (e.g. before adding the listener, check in an other way if the event you are going to listen for already happened) but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js ?

Comment: I just looked at Bacon.js and saw this on the FAQ page (//github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/FAQ) unfortunately: "What's happening here is that your Property won't get updated when there are no listeners. Before you add an actual listener using onValue, the Property is not active; it's not listening to the underlying Bus. It ignores input until someone's interested. So it all boils down to the 'laziness' of all Bacon streams and properties. This is a key feature too: the streams automatically 'plug in' to their sources when a subscriber is added, and 'unplug' when there are no more subscribers."

Comment: @Zjaaspoer: What is your problem with that? No, you're really looking for an FRP libary.

Comment: @Bergi: I'm very sorry if I'm completely oblivious. But I've been reading up on the go-to library for FRP (the above mentioned Bacon.js) for hours and have been experimenting a lot. But I fail to see how, with this programming technique, you are able to fulfill requirement 2. Namely that I want to fire an event and start listening for that event later in time, and still get notified that the event happened.

Comment: You don't use an event stream for that, but a ["property"](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#property) (Bacon terminology)

Comment: @bergi (and benjamin-gruenbaum!): You two seem absolutely right. I'm finding it very hard to grasp this complete new concept (FRP). I indeed found the Properties to be able to have an initial value. I'll be spending quite some time learning this new approach/technique and will try to answer my own question as soon as I feel I can provide a solid solution.

Comment: @Zjaaspoer I'm glad FTP is working out for you. It's really a blessing in some cases. Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @Zjaaspoer Your requirement 1) suggests promises can't be used for events that fire multiple times. That's not entirely accurate. You can use [notify callbacks](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api) to send progress, which can be used as an event system. However, I don't think they would satisfy your requirement 2) without additional code: they only trigger the notification callbacks that have already been registered at the time of the notification.

Comment: You should use a hash table (ie regular javascript object) instead of an array for your `memory` variable, ar at least check if name isn't already in memory before pushing it, otherwise you could have memory and performance issues if broacasting a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A ["property" from bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#property) does exactly what you are asking for.  This falls under the broader category of functional reactive programming (FRP).  The most popular two libraries for this in JavaScript are probably

- [bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#property)
- [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)

Both of which provide the specific tool you're asking for, along with a vast array of alternatives.